# I have just installed VS.NET 2003 which left my newer versions (2005/2008) crippled

Tags: visual-studio

I had Visual Studio 2008 and 2005 installed on my machine , unfartunately i have to install VS.NET 2003 on it to work on an old project. However after the installation now my VS2008 projects are not compiling as they are unable to resolve the .NET core namespaces. I trying reinstalling .NET 3.5 and VS2008 but it still giving me the same errors while building the solution.
anybody had such experience and any tip to solve it?

strangelly VS 2005 is working fine and it means its working fine with .NET 2.0 deployments however its causing issue with ASP.NET MVC project in VS 2008 which is certainly using .NET 3.5 and yes i have given a try to reinstallation as well

Comment: The same thing has happened to me before, and I was able to do a repair as JaredPar suggests below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rifferte is correct in that it's safest to install in the other they are released.

Probably the best thing to do at this point is to repair your Visual Studio 2008 installation.  You can do this through the Control Panel -> Add Remove Programs menu.  This should fix the issues you are seeing.

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but it would be what I would try first.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try the advice here:

http://channa.gunawardena.org/2008/12/installing-visual-studio-2003-after.html

Basically - you actually have to reinstall the framework outside of VS. That being said - the best advice is to always install VS editions in the order they were released.